# Should I use await inside Promise.all?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, promise

I'm building express middleware to make two async calls to the database to check if the username or email are already in use. The functions return promises without a catch, as I want to keep database logic seperate from req/res/next logic, and I have centralised error handling that requires `next` as an argument. In my postman testing on local environment the following code works as expected and my centralised errorhandler returns the error to the client:

```
async checkUsernameExists(username) {
    await this.sequelize.transaction(
      async () =>
        await this.User.findOne({
          where: {
            username,
          },
        }).then(user => {
          if (user) throw new Conflict('Failed. Username already in use.');
        }),
    );
  }  

const checkDuplicateUsernameOrEmail = async (
  { body: { email, username } },
  res,
  next,
) => {

  await Promise.all([
    checkUsernameExists(username),
    checkEmailExists(email),
  ])
    .then(() => next())
    .catch(error => next(error));
};
```

However, as the `checkExists` functions are async, shouldn't they be included in `Promise.all` with await? Or does `Promise.all` do this automatically?

```
await Promise.all([
    await checkUsernameExists(username),
    await checkEmailExists(email),
  ])...
```

This leads to an unhandled promise rejection from checkUsernameExists  and no response is sent back to the client.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> Should I use await inside Promise.all?

No (at least not the way you're doing it). `Promise.all` accepts and expects an *array of Promises*. Once they all resolve, or if one rejects, the `Promise.all` will resolve or reject. If you use `await`, you'll be passing an array of plain non-Promise values to `Promise.all`, which isn't the logic you want. If you use `await`, you'll also be waiting for the Promises to resolve *serially*, rather than in parallel, defeating the entire point of `Promise.all`. For example:

```
await Promise.all([
    await checkUsernameExists(username),
    await checkEmailExists(email),
  ])...
```

If `checkUsernameExists` takes 0.5 seconds to resolve, and `checkEmailExists` also takes 0.5 seconds to resolve, it will take *at least* 1 second for the `Promise.all` to resolve, because the Promises are being resolved via the `await checkUsernameExists`s, not by the `Promise.all` itself.

You should definitely do

```
await Promise.all([
  checkUsernameExists(username),
  checkEmailExists(email),
])
```

Async functions return Promises - to the `Promise.all`, `someFnThatReturnsAPromise()` is the same as `somePromise`. So there's absolutely nothing wrong with invoking the function and putting the resulting Promise in the array to pass to `Promise.all`.

Comment: Doh! Thank you, seems obvious now. That's why the unhandled rejection flag was popping up.